# What's the data structure that works as an array but grows automatically into 2nd dimension when given multiple values under same index?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I remember this data structure which works based on indexes, as in an array or a list. However, if you put several values under the same index, that index turns into a linked list. Thus, upon adding new elements to that same index, the linked list would grow automatically.

I assume it is not just a 2D array. Also I heard it's possible to create an array of linked lists, but I still doubt that it is what I'm interested in.

Also, I assume that this is like some data structure from Java Collection because I remember seeing some code in Java containing this structure, but forgot its name.

Can some come up with some clues what may it be?
Or whether such data structure even exist?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a hash table to me.

Comment: "Also I heard it's possible to create an array of linked lists, but I still doubt that it is what I'm interested in." -- sounds like that's *exactly* what you're interested in. It's unlikely the entries "turned into" lists. Sounds more like a multi-map implementation to me.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own data structure to implement the exact behavior you want.

One way to do this, is to use a `HashMap` of `Integer` as `key` and `LinkedList` as `value`.

Here is an example:

```
public class IndexMap {
    Map<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> map;
    public IndexMap(){
         map = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>>();
    }
    public void add(int index, int value) {
        if(map.containsKey(index)) {
            map.get(index).add(value);
        }else {
            LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
            list.add(value);
            map.put(index, list);
        }
    }
    public void remove(int index, int value) {
        if(map.containsKey(index))
            map.get(index).remove(new Integer(value));
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return map.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IndexMap map = new IndexMap();
        map.add(0,0);
        map.add(0,1);
        map.add(1,0);
        map.add(2,0);
        map.add(2,1);
        System.out.println(map);
        map.remove(0,1);
        System.out.println(map);
    }

}
```

Sample demo:

```
{0=[0, 1], 1=[0], 2=[0, 1]}
{0=[0], 1=[0], 2=[0, 1]}
```

You can alter the methods or add new ones to implement more functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking of a multimap. While there is no implementation in base java, there is one in [google guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap).

[Here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild) are introductions on how to use it in your build.